# Solidity code gives VM exception error when called multiple times

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

## Let's start with my solidity code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Voting {
    address mainAddress;
    bytes32[] candidateNames;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint) candidateVotes;
    mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) candidatesDetails;
    address[] voters;

    function Voting() public {
        mainAddress = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier isMainAddress {
        if (msg.sender == mainAddress) {
            _;
        }
    }

    function getAllCandidates() public view returns (bytes32[]) {
        return candidateNames;
    }

    function setCandidate(bytes32 newCandidate) isMainAddress public {
        candidateNames.push(newCandidate);
    }

    function setVote(bytes32 candidate) public {
        require(validVoters());
        candidateVotes[candidate] = candidateVotes[candidate] + 1;
        voters.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getVote(bytes32 candidate) public view returns (uint) {
        return candidateVotes[candidate];
    }

    function setDescrption(bytes32 candidateName, bytes32 candidatesDesc) isMainAddress public {
        candidatesDetails[candidateName] = candidatesDesc;
    }

    function getDescription(bytes32 candidateName) public view returns (bytes32){
        return candidatesDetails[candidateName];
    }

    function getCurrentAddress() public view returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function validVoters() public view returns (bool) {
        for(uint i = 0; i < voters.length ; i++){
           if (voters[i] == msg.sender) {
                return false;
           } 
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The functions : **Voting(), getAllCandidates(), setCandidate(), getVote(), setDescription(), getDescription(), getCurrentAddress()** works fine when called multiple times. So, I guess we can ignore them for now.

The function **setVote()** runs fine the first time it executes *ie. when a person votes for once*. The problem arises when the same person tries to vote the second time. It gives the following error :

[image]

This might be a beginners mistake but I have been trying to fix this for 2 days straight and now I really need help.

Also,

- I use **Remix - browser based IDE** to run/check my solidity code.
- I use **Ganache** for test accounts.

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function in question:

```
function setVote(bytes32 candidate) public {
    require(validVoters());
    candidateVotes[candidate] = candidateVotes[candidate] + 1;
    voters.push(msg.sender);
}
```

Note that `validVoters()` must return `true` for this function to succeed. If it returns `false`, the `require` will fail and revert the transaction. Also note that at the end of the function, `msg.sender` is added to the array `voters`.

Let's take a look at `validVoters()`:

```
function validVoters() public view returns (bool) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < voters.length ; i++){
       if (voters[i] == msg.sender) {
            return false;
       } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

This function returns `false` if `msg.sender` is in `voters`, which we know will be the case after the account has voted once.

So the second time through, `validVoters()` returns `false`, which causes `require(validVoters())` in `setVote()` to revert the transaction.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to resolve the issue. I know what the code does :D. I tried replacing `require()` with `if statement ...` and the transaction went through with no errors. Lesson learned: `require` and `if` behaves differently. Thanks. This is the second time you helped if you remember @smarx

Comment: Of course, now your voting contract allows someone to vote as many times as they want!

Comment: I ran the code (using `if`), one user can vote only once.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, if you use an `if` to make sure it has no effect on multiple votes, that works. But why are you doing this? What was wrong with `require`? That's a good way to revert the transaction when it's invalid. It's the lowest cost option to the account making the transaction, and it doesn't make it look like an operation succeeded when it didn't.

Comment: Yea, revert would be considered a better option but it kept throwing that nasty error. I plan on handling rest of the operations like `cannot vote, already voted` on the frontend side using react using React. If there is any way to get rid of the error with `require` still in play then please humor me :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. On the front-end, you'll eventually get back a transaction receipt, and that transaction receipt will indicate whether the transaction succeeded or failed. If you use an `if` statement, you won't even be able to tell which happened.